# AppEngine: Retaining orphans in an owned, bidirectional one-to-many relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jdo

I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class SupermarketChain {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String key;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "supermarketChain")
@Basic
private List<Supermarket> supermarkets;
}

@Entity
public class Supermarket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
private String key;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
private SupermarketChain supermarketChain;
}
```

When I'm deleting a parent with em.remove(SupermarketChain.class, key), all orphans will be deleted too. I read the [relevant paragraph](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Dependent_Children_and_Cascading_Deletes) in the documentation, even tried it with JDO with @Element(dependent = "false") but the problem remains. How can I retain the orphans in that relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retaining an orphan makes no sense. In v1 of GAE JDO/JPA all relations are "owned" so you have to have a parent of any child. And if the parent no longer exists then the child is deleted. Always.

In v2 of GAE JDO/JPA you will also be able to have unowned objects, hence there is no "parent" and so they can continue to exist after.

Comment: Retaining (or creating) orphans makes sense in App Engine. Having 2 entities that share a common parent, even if that parent doesn't exist, is how you put things into the same entity group - by having an imaginary entity that is parent to both of them.  This is a case where JDO semantics and App Engine semantics differ enough to cause some confusion I think.  It's not really fair to say "retaining an orphan makes no sense."

Comment: No idea what the difference you refer to between "JDO semantics" and "AppEngine semantics". JDO simply defines an API. It doesn't mandate deletion or otherwise when no parent key (since it doesn't mandate anything about parent keys either). The logic described (by me above) is what the GAE staff embodied in their JDO plugin (as what made sense).